# UIView size that fits its content without auto layout

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

To get fitting height of a `UIView` that uses auto layout to layout its subview/s we can use `systemLayoutSizeFitting`.

What is the alternate way/process to get the fitting height of a UIView that fits its subviews (having multiline UILabels and other dynamic content) that is not using autolayout.

The reason for being specific is that my cell has lots of constraints and I am now trying to avoid the time expensive autolayout calculations.

Comment: If the content is dynamic; why not use a UIScrollView and try contentSize?